# Using HtmlHelper on Model to insert links in returned errors

Tags: cakephp, model, html-helper

I'm working with `CakePHP` and trying to understand the best ways to make my application consistent and logical.

Now I'm trying to working with `Model data validation` and handling validation errors in the `view`, I have a doubt on how should I do if I like to insert some link inside the returned error, for example for a forgotten password.

Is it good to use (if it's possibile) `HtmlHelper` inside the Model to return consistent links inside my application, or should I think about another way?

```
<?php
App::import('Helper', 'Html');
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $validate = array (
        'email' => array (
            'checkEmail' => array (
                'rule' => array('email', true),
                'message' => 'Email not valid message.'
            ),
            'checkUnique' => array (
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'This email is allready in the db, if you forgot the password, '.(string)$this->Html->link('click here', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'password-recover')).'.'   
            )
    )
    // the rest of the code...
```

This doesn't work because it seems I can't chain the message string with HTML string.
Does exist e smartest way to do that, or should I simply insert the html string without the `HtmlHelper`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want HTML in your validation messages CakePHP provides a way to do this, no breaking Cake, no writing a lot of code.

In your `$validation` just use whatever HTML you would like to have presented to the user.

In your view when you create your [`FormHelper::input($fieldName, array $options)`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create) pass the following array to `$options`:

```
$options = array('error' => array(
              'attributes' => array('escape' => false)
               ))
```

[See this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aerror) to learn more about the `$options['error']` ...options.

Alternatively, if you want *all* inputs with no HTML escaping you can pass [`$options['inputDefaults']`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#setting-defaults-for-all-fields) when you create the form.

Comment: to be precise this is the working example: `echo $this->Form->error('User.email', array('class' => 'css-error'), array('escape'=>false));`

Comment: You should be able to put the `array('error' => array('escape' => false))` in your `input()` call without needing to call `$this->Form->error()`.  Unless you're putting up your own form HTML you shouldn't need to call `$this->Form->error()`

Answer (score 2):

this is a difficult topic because

1. you might need to [break MVC](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2007/08/09/how-to-use-a-helper-in-a-controller/)
2. validation is as in your case usually in `$validate` and cannot contain dynamic stuff

for 1)

- you can also use `Router::url()` with manual HTML
- you can use BBcode or pseudo-markup and translate this into real links in the view/element of the flashmessage

for 2)

- use `__construct()` and `$this->validate` to use dynamic elements if needed

---

In PHP, properties of a class (such as `$validate`) have to be [initialized with constant values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            'checkUnique' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'This email address has already been claimed, possibly by you. If this is your email address, use the <a href=":link">reset password</a> facility to regain access to your account'
            ),
        ),
    );

    public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
        $this->validate['email']['checkUnique']['message'] = String::insert(
            $this->validate['email']['checkUnique']['message'],
            array('link' => Router::url(array('action' => 'password-recover')))
        );
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to break "MVC" and validation can certainly contain calls to your own custom defined methods making it as dynamic as it needs to be.

Comment: +1. This answer may have been more clear with an example (which I've added). OP is asking about dynamic validation messages, not custom validation rules. As validation messages have to be constant initially, it makes sense to use psuedo-markup that is later replaced with a link, and `__construct()` would be one of the places you could update a class property with run-time information.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it hard on yourself. The helpers are not accessible in the model and controller. And for good reason: the M and C shouldn't be concerned with the V.

There are ways to do exactly as you want (but involves considerably more code). Since you ask for the smartest way: What's wrong with just echo the reset password link in the view, after the login form? Just `echo 'Forgot your password? '.$this->Html->link('Click here', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'password-recover'));`

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree on breaking the MVC logic. I also tried all the `array('escape' => false)` possible ways (in Form->input, in Form->error and even in the model) and none of them worked with me! (cakephp 2.0)

"Anh Pham" answer is the easiest and simplest way. In addition to that, I returned empty error message from model validation ('errorMessage' => false ; doesn't work in cakePhp 2.0).

Because I wanted to pass a variable to the view to build the link there (MVC), in the **controller** I check if the field is invalidated:

```
$invlaidFields = array_keys($this->Model->validationErrors();    
if ( in_array('myField', $invalidFields)  ){
     ...
     }
```

In the **view**, I check if the field was invalidated, I then echo my error message giving it class error-message so it looks the same as the rest error messages.

```
if ($this->Form->('myFields')) { ... echo '<span class="error-message">error message'. $this->Html->link(...).'</span>'; }
```

Hope it helps somebody out there.

P.S. It's always a good practice to mention what cakePHP version you are using...

Answer (score 0):

To cakephp2 you can use the following:

//model validation

```
'company' => array('notempty' => array('rule' => array('notempty'),'message' => "select one company o send email to <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">contact</a>",),)
```

//front

```
<?php if ($this->Form->isFieldError('Register.company')): ?>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $this->Form->error('Register.company', null, array('escape'=>false)); ?></span>
      <?php endif; ?>
```